# How to combine results of three queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 queries:

```
SELECT If(((cat_id = 9) or (cat_id = 5)),url_download,"") as Maps
FROM `b96e8_jdownloads_files`
where cat_id not in (7,8,4,0,12,10,11)
order by date_added DESC


SELECT If(((cat_id = 11) OR (cat_id = 10)),url_download,"") as Publications
FROM `b96e8_jdownloads_files`
where cat_id not in (7,8,4,9,5,12,0)
order by date_added DESC

select If(cat_id = 12,url_download,"") as Others
FROM `b96e8_jdownloads_files`
where cat_id not in (7,8,4,0,10,11,5,9)
order by date_added DESC
```

I want to combine them to achieve this output. so that I can just get the data from the table and output it.

```
  |             Maps                |         Publications     |              Others         |
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  im_0709.zip                       |  Annual Report 2009.rar  |        ccIlonggoVer.rar
  namriaVacantPosition07 17 14b.rar |             im_0710.zip  |        ccIlocanoVer.rar
  namriaVacantPosition6 27 14.rar   |             im_1208.zip  |        ccFilipinoVer.rar
  namriaVacantPosition5 15 14.rar   |             im_0807.zip  |        BRP Brochure.rar
                                    |                          |        brochureNamria.rar
                                    |                          |        brochureGTC.rar
                                    |                          |        Severe Wind.rar
                                    |                          |        Ground Shaking.rar
                                    |                          |        Flood.rar
```

however when I tried to combine the three queries using this query

```
 SELECT file_title, If(((cat_id = 9) or (cat_id = 5)),url_download,"") as Maps,
 If(((cat_id = 11) OR (cat_id = 10)),url_download,"") as Publications,
 If(cat_id = 12,url_download,"") as Others
 FROM `b96e8_jdownloads_files`
 where cat_id not in (7,8,4,0)
 order by date_added DESC
```

I get this output

```
 |             Maps                |         Publications     |              Others         |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         NULL                      |                    NULL  |        ccIlonggoVer.rar
         NULL                      |                    NULL  |        ccIlocanoVer.rar
         NULL                      |                    NULL  |        ccFilipinoVer.rar
         NULL                      |                    NULL  |        BRP Brochure.rar
                                   |                          |        brochureNamria.rar
                                   |                          |        brochureGTC.rar
                                   |                          |        Severe Wind.rar
                                   |                          |        Ground Shaking.rar
                                   |                          |        Flood.rar
                     NULL          |   Annual Report 2009.rar |        NULL
                im_0709.zip        |                  NULL    |        NULL
                     NULL          |             im_0710.zip  |        NULL
                     NULL          |             im_1208.zip  |        NULL
                     NULL          |             im_0807.zip  |        NULL
 namriaVacantPosition07 17 14b.rar |                  NULL    |        NULL
 namriaVacantPosition06 27 14.rar  |                  NULL    |        NULL
 namriaVacantPosition05 15 14.rar  |                  NULL    |        NULL
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the ordering and why row 0 has those values?
It is if they belong to the day date_added that they're on the same row?

Comment: try pivot table query, perhaps it help

Comment: This is not natural in SQL. You should join the data on the application side.

Answer (score 0):

You use SQL to create a result set of records.

In every record, the fields have some relation to one another.

Now, in your desired output, I dare guess that `namriaVacantPosition07 17 14b.rar`, `im_0710.zip` and `ccIlocanoVer.rar` have absolutely **no** relation to one another, except that they happen to be somewhere in the same database, and **coincidentally** happen to appear on the same line if you put three unrelated lists next to one another.

If there is no logical reason to describe why those three things should appear on the same line, then there is no way to do this in SQL.

And indeed, you should **not** even try to do this. You should not want it. There are three meaningful lists that you retrieve from your DB and the items in those lists are completely unrelated.

Now you want to *display* the three *lists* side by side, that is a *presentation* issue. Make a table, use three columns, whatever. **Do not try to solve presentation issues in your database**. Ever.

You database is about *data*. There should be absolutely no difference in how you retrieve your information, whether you want to display the three lists side-by-side, one under the other, or on three different pages or websites, because those different presentations change *nothing* about the data you want to retrieve!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on SQL with full join on rownum. 
Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't supports full joins, row_number() over and CTE's therefore query is bit complex, but it works:

```
select Maps,Publications,Others from
(
    select  Maps,Publications, Others from
        (
        select @r:=@r+1 as 'Num', e.* 
        from
            (
            select 
                 Maps
                ,Others 
            from
               ( 
                 SELECT 
                     @m:=@m+1 as 'Num'
                     ,d.fname as 'Maps' 
                 from df d 
                 cross join (select @m:=0) t 
                 where cat_id="M" 
                 order by db
                ) maps
            left join 
                (
                SELECT 
                    @n:=@n+1 as 'Num'
                    ,d.fname as 'Others' 
                from df d
                cross join (select @n:=0) t 
                where cat_id="O" order by db 
                ) others on maps.Num=others.Num
            union all
            select  
                 Maps
                ,Others 
            from
                (
                SELECT  
                     @o:=@o+1 as 'Num'
                    ,d.fname as 'Maps' 
                from df d 
                cross join (select @o:=0) t 
                where cat_id="M" 
                order by db
                ) maps
            right join 
                    (
                    SELECT  
                         @p:=@p+1 as 'Num'
                        ,d.fname as 'Others' 
                    from df d 
                    cross join (select @p:=0) t 
                    where cat_id="O" 
                    order by db 
                    ) others on maps.Num=others.Num
            where maps.Num is null
            )e 
            cross join (select @r:=0) t
        )x
        left join 
                (
                SELECT 
                     @q:=@q+1 as 'Num'
                    ,d.fname as 'Publications' 
                from df d 
                cross join (select @q:=0) t 
                where cat_id="P" 
                order by db 
                ) pubs on pubs.Num=x.Num
        union all
        select  
             Maps
            ,Publications
            ,Others 
        from
            (
            select 
                @r1:=@r1+1 as 'Num'
                ,e.* 
            from
                (
                select 
                     Maps
                    ,Others 
                from
                    ( 
                    SELECT 
                         @m1:=@m1+1 as 'Num'
                        ,d.fname as 'Maps' 
                    from df d 
                    cross join (select @m1:=0) t 
                    where cat_id="M" 
                    order by db
                    ) maps
                    left join 
                        (SELECT 
                             @n1:=@n1+1 as 'Num'
                            ,d.fname as 'Others' 
                        from df d 
                        cross join (select @n1:=0) t 
                        where cat_id="O" 
                        order by db 
                        ) others on maps.Num=others.Num
                union all
                select  
                     Maps
                    ,Others 
                from
                    (
                    SELECT  
                         @o1:=@o1+1 as 'Num'
                        ,d.fname as 'Maps' 
                    from df d 
                    cross join (select @o1:=0) t 
                    where cat_id="M" 
                    order by db
                    ) maps
                right join 
                        (
                        SELECT  
                             @p1:=@p1+1 as 'Num'
                            ,d.fname as 'Others' 
                        from df d 
                        cross join 
                            (select @p1:=0) t 
                        where cat_id="O" 
                        order by db
                        ) others on maps.Num=others.Num
                where maps.Num is null
                )e 
                cross join (select @r1:=0) t
            )z
            right join 
                    (
                    SELECT 
                         @q1:=@q1+1 as 'Num'
                        ,d.fname as 'Publications' 
                    from df d 
                    cross join (select @q1:=0) t 
                    where cat_id="P" 
                    order by db
                    ) pubs on pubs.Num=z.Num
            where z.Num is null
)y
```

Full join replaced with left and right join with union all (with monstrous overhead), dt column emulates 'date_added' column.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0afe/42